# Mysql installation failed

Tags: command-line, server, mysql

Mysql server is failed to start suddenly, so I just uninstalled it and tried to reinstall again. But, While installing the mysql server using

```
#apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

I got the following error.

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
2016-02-10 23:14:20 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-02-10 23:14:20 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-02-10 23:14:20 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 31672 ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I saw the error message using `#dmesg` as follows,

```
[270432.510510] init: mysql main process (25270) terminated with status 2
[270432.510537] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[270532.815355] init: mysql main process (25314) terminated with status 2
[270532.815371] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[270633.132158] init: mysql main process (25358) terminated with status 2
[270633.132185] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[270733.731547] init: mysql main process (25407) terminated with status 2
[270733.731606] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[270734.215222] init: mysql main process (26314) terminated with status 2
[270734.215247] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[270734.490352] init: mysql main process (26340) terminated with status 2
[270734.490377] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
[270765.881464] cc1 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
.....
[1982873.800674] Out of memory: Kill process 31793 (mysqld) score 546 or sacrifice child
[1982873.807943] Killed process 31793 (mysqld) total-vm:324564kB, anon-rss:282232kB, file-rss:0kB
[1982873.847242] init: mysql main process (31793) killed by KILL signal
[1982873.847261] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[1982873.869928] init: mysql post-start process (31794) terminated with status 1
[1982875.816435] Out of memory: Kill process 31857 (mysqld) score 548 or sacrifice child
[1982875.818163] Killed process 31857 (mysqld) total-vm:390100kB, anon-rss:283084kB, file-rss:4kB
[1982875.915151] init: mysql main process (31857) killed by KILL signal
[1982875.915199] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

But while seeing the disk space using `df -h` only 3gb is used.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G  3.2G   16G  17% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            235M  4.0K  235M   1% /dev
tmpfs            50M  356K   49M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            246M     0  246M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

So how can i come out from the error?

Comment: *disk space* is not the same thing as *memory*: you may find this related question [Optimising MySQL settings - mysqld running out of memory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/422037/optimising-mysql-settings-mysqld-running-out-of-memory) helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your problem there are in locale configurations your system .

Type this to fixed your problem

first run

> **locale**

generate the missing locale and reconfigure locales

> **sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8" && sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales**

see more : [How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)